# laravel dropzone getRealPath

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dropzone.js

I have a problem implementing uploading logo using dropzone, I have a form like this:

```
<div id="image1" class="image-gallery">
  <img class="images" src="#" />
  <form style="width: 100%; height:100%;" action="{{ url('test2')}}" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  </form>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function gallery() {
  $image = Input::file('image');
  $destinationPath = 'gallery';
  $filename = str_random(12);
  // $filename  = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $path = public_path('gallery/'.$filename);
  Image::make($image - > getRealPath()) - > fit(303, 200) - > save($path);
}
```

and route:

```
Route::post('test2', 'BusinessController@gallery');
```

However I get error message:

> Call to a member function getRealPath() on null

If I try:

> $image = Input::hasFile('image');

I get:

> Call to a member function getRealPath() on boolean

How can I fix this?

Comment: how to I add this code and where?

Comment: Did you include the `script` tag linking `dropzone.js` in the HTML?

Comment: <link href="{{asset('css/dropzone.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/dropzone.js') !!}"></script>

Comment: Please check the `Network` tab of the console and verify that `dropzone.js` is loading with `304` or `200` HTTP status code. If it is red and 404, your script tag's `src` attribute is incorrect.